# Does jQuery or a jQuery plugin have a function that does what this function does?

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if jQuery or a jQuery plugin has a function that does what the following function does:

```
function $array(a /* an ARRAY */, f /* a function */) {
    var $res = $();
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        /* Notice: The result of evaluating f(a[i])
         *         shall always be a jQuery selector
         */
        $res.add(f(a[i]));
    return $res;
}
```

I find this function very useful, but I don't want to reimplement it if it already exists.

---

**EDIT 1:**

I admit the question was not particularly clear. I want to be able to do something like:

```
$('<select>')
.append($array([
    { value: 0, name: 'Item 0' },
    { value: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
    { value: 2, name: 'Item 2' }
], function(option) {
    return $('<option>')
    .val(option.value)
    .html(option.name);
}))
.appendTo('body');
```

Comment: An array and a function, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Actually, that's not quite right if the input of your function is not a jQuery object.  There's also [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), which you could use to make an array-of-jQuery-objects, but doesn't return a jQuery object itself.  So I think neither is exactly what you've got there.

Comment: Unfortunately, `.map` is only one half of what I want. Unfortunately, it turns out that [the other half is not implemented](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1886).